# Does $\gcd$ of values of $n$-th degree primitive integer polynomial always divide $n!$?

Tags: polynomials, conjectures

Let's consider the following conjecture:

> Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots +a_nx^n$ be a primitive non-zero polynomial with integer coefficients and let $g=\gcd(\{f(k), k \in \mathbb{Z}\})$, then $g$ divides $n!$.

Or equivalently just:

> Let $0\not\equiv f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $\gcd(f(k)) \mid c(f)\cdot (\deg f)!$.

Here $c(f)$ is the [content of a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_part_and_content).

Can we prove/disprove this?

**Edit: Found literature reference**

Today I found that $g$ is called the **fixed divisor** of a polynomial and with this I was able to trace the same claim to the article *Uber ganzwertige ganze funktionen* by George Pólya from 1915. Unfortunately the article is in german so I am not sure how the proof goes (various articles mention this claim and cite this one without providing the proof themselves).

**Some thoughts**

I found this based on observation for small degrees. For $n=2$ and $\gcd(a_0,a_1,a_2)=1$ we can prove $g \mid 2$ (see below), and similarly for $n=3$ we can show $g \mid 6=3!$. I also wrote a simple script in Maple to verify over small degrees and coefficients range and haven't found a counterexample yet, so I wonder if this can be proven to hold in general.

It can be useful that $\gcd(\{f(k), k \in \mathbb{Z}\})=\gcd(f(0),f(1),\dots,f(n))$ (or any consecutive $n+1$ integers for that matter). Currently I am thinking that Lagrange interpolation could be perhaps useful in generic case, I worked out that if we know $f$ on consecutive integers $i=0,1,\dots,n$, then the Lagrange interpolation implies
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}  (-1)^{n-i}\binom{x}{i}\binom{x-i-1}{n-i}f(i).
$$
So I guess if we assume $\gcd(f(i))=d$ where $d \not\mid n!$, we should be able to use the above to reach contradiction with $f(x)$ having integer and coprime coefficients, but I wasn't able to.

**Proof for $n=2$**

For $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ and $\gcd(a_0,a_1,a_2)=1$, we want to show $\gcd(f(-1),f(0),f(1)) \mid 2$.
Now $f(-1)=a_0-a_1+a_2$, $f(0)=a_0$, $f(1)=a_0+a_1+a_2$ and so
\begin{align}
\gcd(f(-1),f(0),f(1))
&=\gcd(a_0-a_1+a_2,a_0+a_1+a_2,a_0)\\
&=\gcd(-a_1+a_2,a_1+a_2,a_0)\\
&=\gcd(2a_2,a_1+a_2,a_0)\\
\end{align}

Now $g=\gcd(2a_2,a_1+a_2,a_0) \mid 2a_2$, but $a_2$ is coprime to $g$ (otherwise we had a prime $p\mid a_2, p\mid a_1+a_2, p \mid a_0$ and so $p \mid \gcd(a_2,a_1,a_0)=1$, impossible). Hence $\gcd(2a_2,a_1+a_2,a_0) \mid 2$.

Comment: Why is $a_2$ coprime to $g$?

Comment: Using your approach, the method of differences gives us $\gcd(f(i) ) | n! a_n$ (similar to what you did). So, if you can provide a fix for my above comment, you might be able to complete this.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sure, added clarification of that step. Not sure if that generalizes though, but feel free to post that as an answer if that works.

Comment: My fix for your ending is to show $ \gcd(2a_2, a_1+a_2, a_0) \mid \gcd(2a_2, 2a_1+2a_2, 2a_0) = \gcd(2a_2, 2a_1, 2a_0) = 2$ (which is similar to what you did). I suspect you can deal with the general case that way too. Can you flesh out what happens for $n=3$?

Comment: @CalvinLin It's sort of similar, you take values $f(-1),f(0),f(1),f(2)$ for example and simplify the $\gcd$ to $\gcd(2a_2,a_0,a_1+a_2+a_3,6a_3)$, so I guess using your idea we have it divides $\gcd(2a_2,a_0,a_1+a_2+a_3,6a_3)\mid 6 \gcd(a_2,a_0,a_1+a_2+a_3,a_3)=6$. Will have to think about the general case, but yea that could work, thanks. Feel free to post a generic answer, otherwise i will go through it myself later and try to make it work for generic $n$.

Comment: Yea, it works in the general case. You can show that the coefficients at the $(k+1)$th step of the difference is a multiple of $k!$, and so we can ultimately end up with $n! \gcd(a_0, a_1, \ldots a_n)$ regardless of what actual coefficients we had. If you have trouble pushing through, let me know and I can see how I can help. Nice observation!

Comment: @Sil This is of great interest for me since I am looking for an irreducible criterion for polynomials as universal as possible, and for this, the gcd of its values is a very good approach. Do you know whether we can transform a polynomial with $g\ne 1$ into one with $g=1$ such that the one polynomial is irreducible if and only if the other is ?

Comment: @Peter I am not sure, shift $x \mapsto x + a$ will have the same $g$, and reciprocal polynomial of the original can still have $g \neq 1$ as well... I guess one could just divide by $g$ and work with polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Comment: @Sil I found a simple trick : We can easily transform a polynomial such that it has leading coefficient $1$. If we then reverse the coefficients sequence , we get a polynomial that is not only primitive, but also gives $g=1$.

Comment: @Peter Interesting, what trick is it? And does it preserve the irreducibility?

Comment: It solves my problem, but not yours. Clear is that a $g$ cannot be divisible by a prime greater than the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: @CalvinLin I have added one proof as an answer, it does not directly use finite differences but the idea behind is similar (I am using closed form formula with Stirling numbers), maybe it could be done simpler but at least it is a proof.

Comment: @Peter I understand, I was wondering what was the trick for the sake of the irreducibility issue, but i guess it is off-topic here :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using $g:=\gcd\{f(d), d \geq 1\}=\gcd(b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n)$ where $f(x)$ is expressed as
$$f(x)=b_0+b_1\binom{x}{1}+\dots+b_n\binom{x}{n}.$$
(This is a known result, see [this my older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142427) for example)

Furthermore, having $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots +a_nx^n$, we can express $b_i$'s by
$$
b_i = i!\sum_{k=i}^{n}{k\brace i}a_k.
$$
*Proof:* This follows directly from a [well known identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition) for Stirling numbers of the second kind:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}{k\brace i}(x)_i=x^k.$$
We have $(x)_i=x(x-1)\cdots(x-i+1)=\binom{x}{i}i!$ and then $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \sum_{i=0}^{k}{k\brace i}\binom{x}{i}i!=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{x}{i}\sum_{k=i}^{n} a_k {k\brace i}i!.$$
$\square$

Hence $g=\gcd(b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n)$ and so $g \mid b_i = i!\sum_{k=i}^{n}{k\brace i}a_k$. Now we prove $g\mid n!a_i$ for all $i=0,1,\dots,n$ by induction. First notice that $g\mid b_n= n!\sum_{k=n}^n {k\brace n}a_k=n!a_n$ (a base case). Now assume $g\mid n!a_n, g\mid n!a_{n-1},\dots g\mid n!a_{n-i}$, then
\begin{align}
g 
&\mid b_{n-i-1}=(n-i-1)!\sum_{k=n-i-1}^{n}{k\brace n-i-1}a_k\\
\\&\mid n!\sum_{k=n-i-1}^{n}{k\brace n-i-1}a_k\\
\\&= n!{n-i-1\brace n-i-1}a_{n-i-1}+ n!\sum_{k=n-i}^{n}{k\brace n-i-1}a_k\\
\\&= n!a_{n-i-1}+ \sum_{k=n-i}^{n}{k\brace n-i-1}n!a_k\\
\end{align}
and since by the induction hypothesis $g\mid n!a_k$ in the sum, it follows $g \mid n!a_{n-i-1}$.

So finally we have $g\mid n!a_i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,n$ and hence
$$
g\mid (n!a_0,n!a_1,\dots,n!a_n)=n!\gcd(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n).
$$
Particularly for a primitive polynomial $\gcd(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n)=1$ and
$$
g \mid n!.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The equations $f(k)=a_0+a_1k+\dots+a_nk^n$ for $k=1,\dots,n+1$ give us $f(k)$'s as an integer linear combination of $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$. In a matrix notation we have $V_n=(i^{j-1})$ and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f(1)\\
f(2)\\
\vdots\\
f(n+1)
\end{pmatrix}=V_n\begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
However per [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304898) and especially the method referred by Jean Marie it follows that
$$
n!\begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}=n!V_n^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
f(1)\\
f(2)\\
\vdots\\
f(n+1)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where elements of matrix $n!V_{n}^{-1}$ are
$$
(-1)^{i+j}\sum_{m=i}^{n+1}\frac{n!}{(m-1)!}{m\brack i}\binom{m-1}{j-1}
$$
which are clearly integers. Hence
$$
n!a_i=b_{i,1}f(1)+b_{i,2}f(2)+\dots+b_{i,n}f(n)
$$
for some integers $b_{i,j}$, and since $g\mid f(k)$, we have $g\mid n!a_i$ and so
$$
g\mid \gcd(n!a_0,n!a_1,\dots,n!a_n)=n!\gcd(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n).
$$