# Inverse of a special Vandermonde Matrix with elements $i^{j-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)
$$
V_n=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
1 & 2 & \dots & 2^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & n+1 & \dots & (n+1)^n\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and by observation (and lots of oeis.org searching) I suspect that
$$
V_n^{-1}=(b_{i,j})
$$
with
$$
b_{i,j}=\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{n!}\binom{n}{j-1}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1-i} (-j)^{m}{ n+2\brack i+1+m}
$$
where ${ n\brack m}$ are unsigned [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). Now I wonder how to prove this?

**My attempt**

I am aware there is a Matrix inverse formula for Vandermonde matrices, for example mentioned in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698254/proof-of-vandermonde-matrix-inverse-formula), but I failed to match it to the formula above. Another approach where I got farther was to use the definition of matrix multiplication for $V_{n}^{-1}V_n=(c_{i,j})$ and see whether it simplifies to the identity matrix. Here I've got after some algebra mess (it is lengthy to include here, but I can add if needed) to
$$
c_{i,j}=(-1)^{n+i-j}\sum_{k=n}^{n-i+j}(-1)^{k}{ n+2\brack k+i-j+2} {k+1 \brace n+1}.
$$
(here ${n \brace m}$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) for a change...)
From this we can see that for $j<i$ the sum is empty and we get a zero under the diagonal. For $i=j$ we get $c_{i,i}=1$ on the diagonal. So to finish the proof it needs to be shown there are zeroes above the diagonal, i.e. $c_{i,j}=0$ for $i<j$, and that is where I could not get any further.

Can we prove the last step somehow? Or is there another way to prove the inverse identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula

$$V_n=S_nD_nP_n^T \tag{1}$$

which implies:

$$V_n^{-1}=(P_n^{-1})^T D_n^{-1}\underbrace{S_n^{-1}}_{s_n}\tag{2}$$

where $s_n$, resp. $S_n$, are the lower triangular matrices with Stirling numbers of the first, resp. second kind, $D_n=diag(1!, 2!, \cdots n!)$, and $P_n$ the lower triangular Pascal matrix.

Formula (1) is detailed in lemma 2 of this very interesting [article](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egiacomo.dellariccia/Table%20of%20contents/Yang%20S-L.You2007.pdf) entitled "On a connection between the Pascal, Stirling and Vandermonde matrices" by Yang and You (not Me and You). This article is mentionned in particular [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42018/stirling-numbers-and-inverse-matrices) where you will find other interesting informations.

It must be added that the inverse of Pascal matrix is easy to describe : it is obtained from $P_n$ by multiplying its entries $a_{ij}=\binom{i-1}{j-1}$ by $(-1)^{i+j}$.

From (2), can you retrieve your formula ? (for example the $(-1)^{i+j}$ comes from the above mentionned inversion of $P_n$).

**Remark:** Your attempt looks like verifying that $S_ns_n=I$, a property we have used above.

Comment: Thank you for the great reference! It works indeed, so far using these I have found $b_{i,j}=\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{m+j}}{(m-1)!}s(m,i)\binom{m-1}{j-1}$ which will be easy to transform to that of mine.

Comment: See as well this paper: "Symmetric functions and the Vandermonde matrix" (by Oruç and Akmaz), in particular their Theorem 4.1